# keychain can't add gpg key

Tags: gpg-agent

I'm setting up keychain to manage gpg-agent, with 
`keychain --eval --agents gpg MYGPGKEY`
I get the following:

```
* keychain 2.8.1 ~ http://www.funtoo.org
 * Starting gpg-agent...


 * Adding 1 gpg key(s): DF1A7077
 * Error: Problem adding (is pinentry installed?); giving up
```

I've checked that pinentry is indeed installed (link to pinentry-gnome3).

Digging through /usr/bin/keychain, the line causing trouble is:

`gpg --no-options --use-agent --no-tty --sign --local-user "LOCALUSER" -o >/dev/null 2>&1`

I can call this command, when gpg-agent is running; pinentry-gnome3 prompts for my gpg passphrase, but after I close it, the gpg command doesn't finish.

What is the right way to get gpg working with keychain ?